# How/Where To Set Sendmail Requeue Interval

Tags: linux, smtp, sendmail, message-queuing

Simple question time: where can I define the requeue interval for sendmail? By default SendMail is configured to retry delivery of deferred messages once every hour.  I'd like to set that to be more frequent. Is there a DAEMON option somewhere for this?

-M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*sigh) Found it after googling quite awhile:

To find the current running instance type:

```
# pgrep -lf "Queue runner"
```

To actually change it, modify the /etc/sysconfig/sendmail file (keep in mind that this is for CENTOS). It'll look something like this:

```
DAEMON=yes
QUEUE=1h
```

Change the QUEUE unit to suit your preferences.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help to you,

http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/doc8.12/op-sh-4.html